# CC2540 DK Program SimpleBLE Peripheral Application

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, iar

I have purchased the CC2540 EK I am trying to program the SampleBLE peripeheral onto the CC2540EM. I am using the IAR tool chain and the USB cable is connected directly to the SMARTRF05EB (not using the CC debugger) In IAR I can download the code but the SimpleBLEperipheral does not seem to run.

Looks like the App that came with the CC250EM from the factory has been erased and I am unable to reload that application again.

**What is the exact project workspace that I shoud open?**

**Are there any changes that need to be made to the IAR project so that it can be run on the CC2540EM?**

The IAR project name is SimpleBLEPeripheral - CC2540DK- MiniKeyfob - this seems to suggest that it is meant for the keyfob and not the CC2540EM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to the build option.
You got to set the build option to "cc2540", instead of "cc2540df-mini keyfob"...

In IAR, you can set the build option in the drop-down menu in the Workspace area. (it's right under the word "Workspace")

After doing this, compile and reload the hex file to the module. 
It should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: The drop-down menu can easily go unnoticed for a first time user of the Workbench. I spent hours struggling before I discovered it. Then had I read instructions things had been smooth..